# Substitution for list elements in scheme

Tags: scheme, substitution

```
(define (substitute s old new)
(if (null? s)
  '()
(if (list? (car s) false)
    (cond ((eq? (car s) old)
          (cons new (substitute (cdr s) old new)))
          (else 
          (cons (car s) (substitute (cdr s) old new)))))
(if (list? (car s)
    (cons (substitute (car s) old new) (substitute (cdr s) old new))))))
```

The error that I am getting says that this is bad syntax - any clue as to why that might be?
The function is supposed to take in a list, as well as an old word which, if it exists in the list, is replaced by the new word.

Answer (score 0):

```
(if (list? (car s) false)
```

I expect you think this means "if (car s) is not a list" but this is actually invalid because you pass 2 parameters to `list?`, which expects only one. Please look up the correct syntax for [conditionals](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html) and especially the syntax for `if`.

Also, there are a few parentheses errors in your code, and it is absolutely essential that you properly indent your code for your own understanding.

Here's your code, corrected:

```
(define (substitute s old new)
  (if (null? s)
      '()
      (if (list? (car s))
          ; true
          (cons (substitute (car s) old new) (substitute (cdr s) old new))
          ; false
          (cond ((eq? (car s) old)
                 (cons new (substitute (cdr s) old new)))
                (else 
                 (cons (car s) (substitute (cdr s) old new)))))))
```

but cascading `if`s and `cond`s are usually best put into a single `cond` such as:

```
(define (substitute s old new)
  (cond
    ((null? s) 
     '())
    ((list? (car s))
     (cons (substitute (car s) old new) (substitute (cdr s) old new)))
    ((eq? (car s) old)
     (cons new (substitute (cdr s) old new)))
    (else 
     (cons (car s) (substitute (cdr s) old new)))))
```

Testing:

```
> (substitute '(a b (h e l l o) c) 'l 'x)
'(a b (h e x x o) c)
> (substitute '(a b c) 'b 'x)
'(a x c)
```